# ページによって閲覧数が異なるのはなぜか？

Tags: サポート

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

自分のページに載っている質問したページの閲覧数（上記画像参照）と
実際の質問のページの閲覧数が異なるのはなぜでしょうか？

また、その直し方についてですが、
ページを更新するだけでこれらの閲覧数はかならず一致するのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

キャッシングです。英語版ではヒット数が非常に多いため、実際の閲覧数を出すのが実現的ではありません。

そのため、定期的にしか更新しません。

更に、閲覧数が多いため、閲覧数の歴史を保存しません。例えば、社員でも○○月○○日の閲覧数は見えません。

英語が読めたら、下記のサイトで回答が記載しています：

http://shouldiblamecaching.com/